# How can i add custom fields to registration form ? wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration

How can I add custom fields to this register code ? For example I want add "Company name". In this form we have only basic fields.

my code:

```
<div class="registration">
            <form name="registerform" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post">
                <p>
                    <label for="user_login">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_login" value="">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="user_email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="">
                </p>
                <p style="display:none">
                    <label for="confirm_email">Please leave this field empty</label>
                    <input type="text" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" value="">
                </p>

                <p id="reg_passmail">A password will be e-mailed to you.</p>

                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/login/?action=register&success=1" />
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Register" /></p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

This code will add an custom field called Company Name and make it mandatory for registration.  You can follow the WordPress [customizing registration](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form) form online.

```
function myplugin_add_registration_fields() {

    //Get and set any values already sent
    $company_name = ( isset( $_POST['company_name'] ) ? $_POST['company_name'] : '' );
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="company_name"><?php _e( 'Company Name', 'myplugin_textdomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $company_name ) ); ?>" size="50" /></label>
    </p>

    <?php
}

add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_add_registration_fields' );

function myplugin_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty ( $_POST['company_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'company_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Company name is required.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3 );


function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['company_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'company_name', $_POST['company_name']);

}

add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: something is wrong in Your code but solution is in link "customizing registration" everything fine ! thanks :)

Comment: Adding the field to the admin panel is a whole different piece of work that wasn't asked in the question.  You can copy the code from the tutorial it's all there :)

Comment: It was missing a bracket when I set the company name so I have modified the code above.  You should learn how to read the WordPress debug file, it will show you straight away that a single bracket was missing and you could fix it yourself :)